# Converting $\left(\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y}\right)^2 $ to Polar

Tags: partial-derivative

I apologize about the title as I would have included the entire identity I am trying to prove analytically but we are limited to 150 characters.

I'm given the following problem in Widder's *Advanced Calculus*:

> 11.) $u=f\left(x,y\right),x=r\cos\left(\theta\right),y=r\sin\left(\theta\right).$
>   show that \begin{align} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial
>  x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial
> y}\right)^2&=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  r}\right)^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right)^2. \end{align}

This is what I have done so far:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y}\right)^2&=\left(\frac{\partial f\left(r\cos\left(\theta\right),r\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{\partial\left(r\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f\left(r\cos\left(\theta\right),r\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{\partial \left(r\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}\right)^2\\
\end{align}
but is there a way to transform the RHS into what he has written? Perhaps via some substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ using chain rule:

$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\cos \theta \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right) - \frac{\sin \theta}{r} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right) 
\end{align}
$

and

$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}=\sin \theta \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{\cos \theta}{r} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)
\end{align}
$

Now by taking squares, we have:

$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)^2
\end{align}
$

Comment: I already did that actually, I apologize. I have shown that in doing that, the LHS does indeed transform into the right. I suppose what my actual question should be is, how do I transform the LHS into the RHS?